# Different between api scope and user claim in identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

i am reading the identityserver4 guildence, here is the example code

```
        UserClaims =
        {
            new UserClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Name),
            new UserClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Email)
        },

        // this API defines two scopes
        Scopes =
        {
            new Scope()
            {
                Name = "api2.full_access",
                DisplayName = "Full access to API 2",
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "api2.read_only",
                DisplayName = "Read only access to API 2"
            }
        }
```

my questions is
seems the scope is used to control which client can access the api resources, and user claims controler the user permission on apis. let's take a look at "api2.read_only", does this mean client with this scope can only have the read access to the apis? but what if the user has for example: write access for a speicific api? i get confuse about the these two. 
thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes defines whether you have access to the API or not. Where as Claims are more granular. Within the API, what resource you can access? for example, you can access identity resource like name.

Answer (score 2):

Scopes are special claims which define what resources a client can have access to.
User claims are just assertions about a user. You would normally give a user a "role" or "permission" claim (or something like that). By using the user claims you can do some claims authorization if doing authorization based on scopes does not satisfy your requirements.